# Refresh calculation after combobox selection?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a drop down combo box, and I also have a text box that has a Macro that does a DLOOKUP then throws the result into the blank text box.  This part is working decently enough.

What's frustrating is that it doesn't update the result text box.  I need to go back and forth on a record to see the change.

Of course, what I want is for the macro to run as soon as the Combobox is selected then update the result text box with the new number.  I'm sure this is easy to do but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Edit:
I've put the following code in my After Update event...

```
Sub updateDM()
    KeyID = Me!DMID.Value 'vDMID.Value
    If IsNull(KeyID) = False Then
      AssignedPlan = DLookup("AssignedPlan", "DMPlanSum", "DMID = " & KeyID)
      vAssignedPlan.Value = AssignedPlan
      Me.Refresh
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub vStartMonth_AfterUpdate()
  updateDM
End Sub
```

Weird thing about it is that it kindof works, but only if I do the drop down TWICE.  For example, let's say I'm on plan A = result 100 (starting selection).  I choose Plan B = 200, but result box still has 100.  I select Plan B again, result box now changes to 200.

On the other hand, if I change back to Plan A after choosing Plan B, it still changes to 200!

It seems like it's one step behind??

Comment: Have you tried using the `beforeUpdate` and `afterUpdate` events of your combo box?

Comment: Yes I have the script in After Update on the combobox -- haven't tried in Before Update although not sure why that would matter?

Comment: Do you need to refresh the data source of your form?

Comment: Well, yes... the drop down selects a new "Plan Type" which then recalculates a sales rep's plan, the result box shows the new plan calculated out (it's already stored in the table)

Answer (score 0):

remove that code from form_update and stick it to the combobox_before/after_update event.

just assign the value directly to the textbox.

```
Private Sub ComboBox_AfterUpdate()
  me.txt_resultBox.value = nz(DLookup("AssignedPlan", "DMPlanSum", "DMID = " & ComboBox.value),"")
End Sub
```

Comment: (sorry for the delay)  This seemed to work, but only once!  If I choose another from the combobox it won't refresh unless I cycle the records again